# regular expression: chopping last character if second last is upper case?

Tags: python, regex

I want to chop off last character if it is lower case and second last one is upper case. For example.

```
14-ME -> 14-ME
MEA  -> MEA
MEAm -> MEA  #like this one
mama -> mama
```

How to write the regx ? I am thinking of something like r"(.+?)" but not sure how to do conditional thing on the last part. The word could have anything like ()-,+ too.

thanks

Comment: Don't forget to think about what you'll do if the second-last/last character is punctuation (i.e. whether you'd count is lower or upper case). e.g. `ME+m`,`MEA+`.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee - that's a good point, also if T.g. cares about unicode and other languages that might also have the notion of 'upper case'.

Comment: Currently I just "hope" that there won't be too many punctuation. I still have to do some manual inspection but this one just serve as some crude filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't really need a regex to do this when you can write a simple piece of code to do it.

```
def chop_char(some_string):
    try:
        # determine if the second to last character is upper case
        if some_string[-2].istitle() and not some_string[-1].istitle():
            return some_string[:-1] # slice off the last character
    except IndexError:
        # string isn't long enough to have a 2nd to last char (i.e. it's only 1 character)
        pass
    return some_string
```

Or if you don't want the exception stuff...

```
def chop_char(s):
    if len(s) > 1:
        if s[-2].istitle() and not s[-1].istitle():
            return s[:-1]
    return s
```

Comment: thanks, actually I did the same thing but I just wonder if the regular expression solution is available. Since this word is extracted from some equation (ex: ME14 + H2O => ADPm) by another regex. So I thought it would be better if I did it in one step.

Comment: @Tg.- in that case you will need to bolt in mathematical.coffee's solution into yours, which uses a capturing group to get everything but the last character if it meets the same conditions you wanted, but in terms of simplicity it might be better just to use a function depending on how complex your regexes are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Try `r"(.+[A-Z])[a-z]\b"`.

```
import re
regex = r"(.+[A-Z])[a-z]\b"

re.match(regex,'14-ME') # None
re.match(regex,'MEA') # None
re.match(regex,'MEAm') # <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x.. >
re.match(regex,'mama') # None
```

For those objects that match you can grab out all but the last character using `.group`:

```
a = re.match(regex,'MEAm')
a.group(1) # 'MEA'
```

Comment: I like @birryree's `chop_char` solution better though - simpler and doesn't need extra modules.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it with a regexp.

```
strings = ["14-ME","MEA","MEAm","mama"]
p = re.compile(r"([A-Z])[a-z]$")
for s in strings:
    print p.sub(r"\1", s)
```

which gives

```
14-ME
MEA
MEA
mama
```

It wasn't clear to me if you wanted it to match the end of the string, but that's what my regexp does.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about python regex (or any regex really), but you probably want some thing to match like: [list of uppercase letters][list of lowercase letter][end of word]

Comment: [A-Z]+[a-z]$ would be that regex. (one lower case at the end needs another + for multiple)

Comment: I knew the basic of regex, but I stuck at how to omit the last one "if" the second last is uppercase.